# django storages with boto using pirvate ACL throws 404 on save

Tags: acl, private, boto, django-storage

I am using django-storages with boto. Everything works fine if I let storages handle S3 file uploads in my model as public.
However when I set the ACL to private on save/update I get this error message

```
S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>https:/s3.amazonaws.com/mahbuckit/mods/1366814943/1363379259-re6pc-x-l4d2-the-witch-psd-jpgcopy.zip</Key><RequestId>9631D1222C18F323</RequestId><HostId>bmMgn75bqITigKJWM7L7JrjN2TcsPCslOt9d3LX6WvzxWbHcdBfeqBIdFSZsmhXW</HostId></Error>
```

This happens on Add/update of record.

This is my save part for the Model where I have FileFIeld. I override to set the acl to private.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.file:
            conn = boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
            bucket = conn.create_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
            k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
            k.key = settings.MEDIA_URL + self.file.name
            k.set_acl('private')
```

However the file saves all ok. It's the damn errors.

Comment: Where do you actually put the content of the file to S3?  I don't see it happening in the code above.

Comment: I am using django storages. It handles the actual file upload.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In reference to the good person whose work I used and modified http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2012/09/26/django-s3-temporary.php

I noticed that I construct the Key with URL. authors points out in twitter. Which is the whole reason for the error message. Lack of sleep but the error message clearly says missing Key but shows a URL instead of a key. That my problem right there. Key should be a file or path+file name.

Comment: I must say I still get 404 on form post on production but not locally after my fix mentioned above. I think I may have missed something or a new problem has cropped up.

Comment: The post you cite looks quite useful, but is quite out of date. Any references to do the same that are more up to date?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from what I've tested, you need the k.key to reflect self.file.name:

```
k.key = self.file.name
```

Comment: you may be on track with this one. I will try it out and revert back.